# Centre of Mass of a Quadrant of a Square from which a Quadrant of a Circle is Cut

Tags: mathematical-physics

The wing of a hang-glider is a uniform lamina, formed by removing from a square of side $l$ a quadrant of a circle of radius $l$, with its centre at one corner of the square. Find the distance of the centre of mass (COM) of the wing from the opposite corner.

Answer should be $0.316l$

Tried finding the COM of the circle quadrant using

$$\frac{2l\sin\alpha}{3\alpha}$$

with $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and subtracting from $\sqrt2l$.

How would you do this?

Comment: Right idea, wrong value. The square’s CM is not at $\sqrt2l$.

Comment: $\sqrt2l$ was intended to be the length of the diagonal of the square from corner to corner, in this case.

Comment: CM of the square itself would be $\frac{l}{2}$.

Comment: If you're measuring along the diagonal, it's at $\frac{\sqrt2}2l$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can treat each piece as having its entire mass concentrated at its CM and use the formula for a set of point masses:$$
\mathbf r_{CM}=\frac1M\sum m_i\mathbf r_i.
$$ In this case, that gives $$
m_{\text{square}}\mathbf r_{\text{square}}=m_{\text{sector}}\mathbf r_{\text{sector}}+m_{\text{wing}}\mathbf r_{\text{wing}}.$$ By symmetry, of course, we need only work with distances along the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I worked it out myself a few hours ago in the same way - see my answer below. I took the distances along the diagonal, as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$l^2 * \frac{\sqrt2l}{2} - \frac{\pi l^2}{4} * \frac{8l}{3\pi \sqrt2} = (1-\frac{\pi}{4})l^2 * x$$

So, on simplifying $$ l^2*\frac{\sqrt2l}{2} - \frac{2l^3}{3 \sqrt2} = (1-\frac{\pi}{4})l^2 * x $$

So COM is $$ x=1.098l$$ from the corner of the quadrant of the circle.

Now from the opposite corner, the distance of the COM is $$\sqrt2 -x = 0.316l$$

$\sqrt2$ being the whole length of the diagonal.